# How to reduce the memory usage of this code/bufferedreader

Tags: java, memory-management, bufferedreader

I'm trying to reduce the amount of memory the code below uses. I'd like it to use 5-10MB of RAM max, but I'm not sure if that'll be possible. On start-up, it now takes around 10,1MB and after the `Thread.sleep` around 40MB. I've tried using different implementations of `BufferedReader`, but that didn't seem to change anything. I'm not the greatest at java and I'm especially bad at memory management, so I've probably missed some really dumb stuff. It'd be awesome if someone could give me some directions on improving the code regarding memory management!

```
package tsviewerscanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TSViewerScanner {

    static URL url;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                url = new URL("https://www.tsviewer.com/ts3viewer.php?ID=1040506");
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                    String WebContentStr = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                    if (WebContentStr.toLowerCase().contains("error code: 2568") && WebContentStr.toLowerCase().contains("insufficient client permissions")) {
                        System.out.println("WebContentStr contains both strings");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Strings not found");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why?  Is there a reason?

Comment: Converting the string to lowercase once instead of twice will help, as would reading and testing the URL line by lines instead of collecting it all into one giant string. The `BufferedReader` doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Partially because I want to run parts of this code on a machine that has very little RAM available. Partially because I think it's interesting to reduce the amount of resources the code uses and it feels wasteful to use more resources than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main memory utilization issue with this code is that the entire response is loaded into memory before being checked for the existence of the strings.

Rather than buffer the whole stream into one big string you could check each line as they are read, once checked the old lines can be garbage collected.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    AtomicBoolean hasError = new AtomicBoolean();
    AtomicBoolean hasInsufficentPermission = new AtomicBoolean();
    reader.lines().map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(line-> {
        if(line.contains("error code: 2568")) hasError.set(true);
        if(line.contains("insufficient client permissions")) hasInsufficentPermission.set(true);
    });
    if (hasError.get() && hasInsufficentPermission.get()) {
        System.out.println("WebContentStr contains both strings");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Strings not found");
    }
}
```

However I suspect the behaviour you are seeing is more to do with you misunderstanding how the JVM utilizes memory.
The amount of memory that the JVM uses has more to do with how much it has been allocated , how long the program is running for and how much garbage the program creates as it runs.
The memory usage of the JVM is typically not indicative of how much heap application requires at any given time.
There are a number of ways that JVM memory usage can be tuned, but that is out of scope for this answer.

Comment: `error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
if(line.contains("error code: 2568")) hasError = true;
error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
if(line.contains("insufficient client permissions")) hasInsufficentPermission = true;`  

I guess a lambda expression shouldn't be used, since it's used in a loop, which makes it not (effectively) final at all.

Comment: Ah my bad, I've updated the answer to use `AtomicBoolean.` But you could just use a readline loop instead.